# Where is respondent_id in Surveymonkey API v3?

Tags: surveymonkey

The page at 
https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Transitioning-to-SurveyMonkey-s-v3-API

says that what was

POST get_respondent_list

is now

GET /surveys/{id}/responses OR GET /collectors/{id}/responses

But the responses have NO respondent IDs.

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/?python#surveys-id-responses-bulk

Where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The respondent ID is labelled as just `id` in the body. The `respondent_id` is just called `response_id` in API V3, there is no distinction between a response and a respondent.

For example in the list:

```
/v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses
{
  "per_page": 50,
  "total": 10,
  "data": [
    {
      "href": "...",
      "id": "<respondent_id>"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Or in the details,

```
/v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<respondent_id>
{
  "id": "<respondent_id>",
  "collector_id": "<collector_id>",
  "survey_id": "<survey_id>",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks GK. My V2 mindset has response_id as distinct for each response to each question for each respondent so in the interim I can create an autonumber ID.  I note that IDs are now strings 11 digits long eg 10764853680 so well beyond 32-bit Integer size. I've been using Double to store them, should switch to String now.